# figure 8 homeomorphism to line

Tags: differential-geometry

It is fairly easy to intuitively understand  that the 8-figure is not locally homeomorphic to the line, but it would be extremely helpful if someone could point me to a more formal proof.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: You probably know that one invariant of a topological space $X$ is its number of connected components. One way to generalize this notion is to ask: "after removing a point $x$ from $X$, how many connected components does the resulting space $X \setminus x$ have?"

Can you think of a way to bootstrap this and distinguish the spaces?